How formidable forms repeater tag [foreach] not properly displaying around <TR> tag html <table>?
asper the tutorial we can open and close [foreach] tag around <tr> </tr> tag . as per the tutorial i placed the [foreach] tag into html, after updating the changes. when i check the "visual" opening and closing [foreach] tag displays at the top of the document before ....
This is the code is used as per tutorials
**[foreach 369]
<tr>
<td class="xl1515879" height="22"></td>
<td class="xl6515879"></td>
<td class="xl6815879" colspan="1">[371]</td>
<td class="xl1515879" height="22">[372]</td>
<td class="xl1515879" height="22"></td>
</tr>
[/foreach]**

but after updating the form the [foreach 369][/foreach 369] goes outside the  tag before table starts. anyone have idea to fix it; i tide by placing the code in visual are. but doent work !
I'm expecting an answer to fix and set the [/foreach] tag as per the instructions provided by formidable forms !
